# Show variable exactly 3 times more than other variables

Tags: php, function, variables

```
$first = "Text 1"  
$second = "Text 2"  
$third = "Text 3"  
$fourth = "Text 4"  
$fifth = "Text 5"
```

I want to create a function that shows $second and $fourth exactly 3 times more often than the other variables.

How to do this?

Comment: I tried working with probability, but found out, that it was not what i wanted, as it is random which text that gets chosen. So now i'm stuck in what to do.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Does it matter what order they come up in?

Comment: No the order doesn't matter

Comment: Please explain better exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Think of it like advertising. 1 company pays to get their ad shown 3 times more often on the page than the others.

Comment: How often does it need to change? Every page load? Every day?

Comment: Hi Sean, I'll like to know how to do both with change on page load but also one that only changes once a day.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array($first, $second, $second, $second, $third, $fourth, $fourth, $fourth, $fifth);
$elem = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
```

this will go from numbers to values of your variables

Comment: I'm i'm just getting numbers written on the page, sometimes 0, sometimes 7, sometimes 3 (when reloading the page)

It should write out the value of the variable.

Comment: Use `$arr[$elem]`. `$elem` just contains a random key from the array. (See [php.net/array_rand](http://php.net/array_rand)

Comment: Thank you, but the function is random. I'm looking for a way to display 2 and 4 exactly 3 times more, every time

Comment: Yes the probability will be 3 times larger but that doesn't mean that it'll get shown 3 times as much as the others.
I did a little test, reloading the page 12 times, and counted the number of times. 1 = 3 times ---  2 = 2 times ---  3 = 3 times --- 4 = 3 times --- 5 = 3 times.

Comment: Oh - the variable 2 is shown 2 times. So as you can see it is not 3 times more often than the others.

Comment: Don't understand how you get 14?